# is there an installer for xubuntu that works on 32bit and 64bit systems?

Tags: xubuntu, 64-bit, iso, 32-bit

I have a friend who has a laptop from like 2008. He is running Xubuntu 10.04. he asked me to upgrade his system. But I have no idea if he has a 32-bit system or a 64-bit system. He doesn't know which architecture he is running, and I have to make him a install USB. Is there a ISO that works on 32 bit, and 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about a tool called [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) it lets me put multiple Linux live CDs onto one USB. so I did that with both the 64bit, and the 32bit installers

Comment: Good luck helping your friend :-)

Answer (score 3):

As such, there is no "dual installer" for Xubuntu [(see the official site)](https://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) that can detect CPU architecture and decide whether to install a 32 bit or 64 bit system as appropriate. However, [as explained in answer by @sudodus](https://askubuntu.com/a/857026/527764) the 32 bit version of the OS may be installed on 32 bit or 64 bit architecture (the reverse is not the case, of course), so if in doubt, the 32 bit iso may be used.

What you should do is run:

```
uname -i
```

This will give you the architecture of your friend's system so that then you can download the appropriate iso.

Comment: @zana, impressive edit really drops out the `meat` in the post, Thanks for the counsel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are installers, that can run and install in almost all PC computers with Intel or AMD processors from 2008. One alternative is to try with a USB pendrive with a 32-bit version of Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Such a system works in both 32-bit and 64-bit computers.

Another alternative is to download both Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS iso files and create two USB or DVD boot drives, one with a 32-bit operating system and one with a 64-bit operating system.

One the other hand, if your friend wants to do a release upgrade, it can be done without any separate boot drive, by running this command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This works from one release (alias version) to the next one (time-wise), and also to skip from one LTS release to the next LTS release, for example

- from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS
- from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

It this is not the case, it is almost always best to make a fresh installation of the new system.

-o-

But before you start upgrading or re-installing, I recommend that you **backup** the current system or at the very least, your friend's personal files, because upgrading to a new release is risky.

And it is also a good idea to **Try Xubuntu** (running a 'live session' booted from a USB or DVD drive with the new version) before deciding to go ahead.